# Merging values from an item in an array and an object in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash, array-merge

So I was working with redux and reactjs, although the question is not related:

I have this collection

```
const items = [
  {id: 0, name: 'one'},
  {id: 1, name: 'two'},
  {id: 2, name: 'three'}
]

const itemsWithTheFlag = [
  {id: 0, flag: false},
  {id: 1, flag: true},
  {id: 2, flag: false},
]
```

Then my initial state is:

```
{
  items: items
}
```

Now I wonder how can I perform find and update in `items` array,

One of my functions is mocking an `async` request and receiving item from `itemsWithTheFlag`

```
export function fetch(id) {
  const desiredItem = find(itemsWithTheFlag, (item) => (item.id === id))
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(receiveItem(desiredItem))
        resolve()
      }, 100)
    })
  }
}
```

Now I want help to update the state, with updated `merged` values, I receive from `fetch` and the initial state `items`

```
[RECEIVE_ITEM]: (state, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    // how ??
  })
}
```

I want to keep the immutability of course, using lodash is fine as well

Comment: `itemsWithTheFlag ` has duplicate ids. Is it intentional or just a typo?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko yes it is a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate entire array and patch item with corresponding id.

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    items: state.items.map(
       item => (
         item.id === action.desiredItem.id
         ? Object.assign({}, item, desiredItem)
         : item)
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a new array, with just that item swapped out. This way has the benefit of not going over all of `state.items`, which is a bit more performant on large arrays (but the solution in this instance does use lodash)

```
const index = _.findIndex(state.items, { id: action.newItem.id });
return {
  ...state,
  items: [
    ...state.items.slice(0, index),
    { ...state.items[index], ...action.newItem },
    ...state.items.slice(index + 1)
  ]
};
```